# Connection refused on hadoop fs -ls

Tags: hadoop, vagrant

I have been following some instructions on setting-up a vagrant single-node cluster and have been through the instrustions once without issue. However, I am running into several problems when trying to repeat the same instructions. Now I am getting a connection refused when trying to run hadoop fs -ls /

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

15/01/18 04:09:21 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
15/01/18 04:09:22 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
15/01/18 04:09:23 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
15/01/18 04:09:24 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
15/01/18 04:09:25 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
15/01/18 04:09:26 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
15/01/18 04:09:27 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
15/01/18 04:09:28 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
15/01/18 04:09:29 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
15/01/18 04:09:30 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
ls: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

When I run jps I get the following:

```
$jps
4176 JobTracker
4313 TaskTracker
3970 DataNode
4581 Jps
4094 SecondaryNameNode
```

I'm really at a loss as to what I have missed to cause this different behavior. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your namenode is not up. Make sure u format the namenode

- stop the cluster and stop all daemons
- format the namenode

Once you format, try starting namenode first and other daemons.

Comment: Both answers were equally helpful. But these steps precisely fixed my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the daemons running there is no name node. I would suggest you go ahead and restart all the daemons. Below are the commands which just restart the daemons and name node will be up and running. Hope this helps!

```
sudo service hadoop-master stop
sudo service hadoop-master start
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
sudo jps
```